# QHostAddress setAddress not working

Tags: c++, qt

I need to change my host IP Address on Linux app using Qt. I have readed documentation about QHostAddress and method setAddress in this class that say the following:

> "Sets the IPv4 or IPv6 address specified by the string representation >specified by address (e.g. "127.0.0.1"). Returns true and sets the address >if the address was successfully parsed; otherwise returns false."

I know that it is possible using QProccess but I'm trying to use Qt-way in order to do that. I'm very confused becuase my app is not in running with root privileges so I find very difficult perform this action using Qt class directly. Then I try this:

```
QHostAddress hostAddress;
bool ipChange = hostAddress.setAddress("192.168.1.143");
if(ipChange) qDebug() << "IP ADDRESS CHANGED";
else qDebug() << "IP ADDRESS NOT CHANGED";
```

The result of this code is `"IP ADDRESS CHANGED"` but doing `ifconfig` in a terminal, my IP address has not been modified. So, my questions are:

1. How I can do that?
2. Why I can see `IP ADDRESS CHANGED` if this method obviously doesn't works?

Comment: What??? `QHostAddress` is a class that *represents* an IP address. If you want to change an IP address of a network interface of your system you need to invoke the right syscalls or the right programs that do that! (On Linux it would be `ip addr add IP/NETMASK dev ethN`, and a corresponding `del` to get rid of the old one)

Comment: Thanks @peppe, I misunderstand this class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the address stored in `hostAddress`.  You can now use `hostAddress` to (e.g.) open a stream socket to a port on `192.168.1.143`.  This has no relation to any IP addresses of the host you happen to be running on - `QHostAddress` is just a representation of any IP address.

To set an address for a network interface on the host machine, you will need to be root, and to use the native facilities (or an external process - `/sbin/ifconfig`, for example).

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstand this class